# Pydantic create nested structure from single object

Tags: python, pydantic

Trying to figure out how to create nested attributes in Pydantic from a single SQLAlchemy object. Currently I've got:

SQLAlchemy model:

```
class FooORM(BaseORM):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer)
    cost_high = Column(Integer)
    cost_low = Column(Integer)
```

Pydantic schema:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict    
class FooModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True) 
    id: int
    cost_high: int
    cost_low: int
```

This will result in:

```
{"id": 1, "cost_high": 5, "cost_low": 0}
```

How do I modify the schema to create the output:

```
{"id": 1, "cost": {"high": 5, "low": 0}}
```

I've thought about:

```
class Cost(BaseModel):
    high: int
    low: int

class FooModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True) 
    id: int
    cost: Cost
```

But that obviously doesn't pass the `cost_high` to `Cost.high`.  I can do the reverse process and flatten a nested model using a `Field` with `PathAlias`, but I can't work out how that would apply in nesting attributes, what have I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [Computed Fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/computed_fields/) (Pydantic V2)

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, computed_field, Field
data = {'id': 1, 'cost_high': 5, 'cost_low': 0}

class Cost(BaseModel):
    high: int
    low: int

class FooModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True) 
    id: int
    cost_high: int = Field(exclude=True)
    cost_low: int = Field(exclude=True)

    @computed_field
    @property
    def cost(self) -> Cost:
        return Cost(high=self.cost_high, low=self.cost_low)

a = FooModel(**data)
print(a.model_dump())

#{'id': 1, 'cost': {'high': 5, 'low': 0}}
```